# Using Apache's rewrite module to set up local host names for development

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have several websites on my development machine under Apache's htdocs folder. Apache Directory root is htdocs, but I want to be able to access each different site there by individual domain names. For example, I have

```
htdocs/dev_site_com
htdocs/cre_site_com
```

I have added these lines to my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       dev.site.localhost

127.0.0.1       cre.site.localhost
```

Now I want to add an .htaccess file in the htdocs to redirect `dev.site.localhost` request to `htdocs/dev_site_com` or `127.0.0.1/dev_site_com`

I want to do this so that all of my relative URLs in my site work locally. If I link to a stylesheet in the dev_site_com site using the path `/css/style.css`, it will work in production, but not in development, because the root is htdocs and not htdocs/dev_site_com

I've never been good with mod_rewrite.. but this is what I have so far..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^dev\.site\.localhost
    RewriteRule %1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

and nothing is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not usually use rewrite rules to set up different host names on a local server.  Instead you would edit your Apache configuration and set up new virtual hosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/dev_site_com
    ServerName dev.site.localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/cre_site_com
    ServerName cre.site.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

You don't say what type of operating system you are running.  If I were doing this on my Ubuntu Linux server I would create two files:

- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/dev`
- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/cre`

These contain the the virtual host directive for each site respectively.

I would then enable each site with the command `a2ensite` and restart Apache:
`sudo a2ensite dev && sudo a2ensite cre &&  sudo service apache2 restart`.

Here is a [full guide to virtual host setup on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts).